# Fragments, FrameLayout how to make is scrollable?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I am very confused, I have app with 3 fragments and DrawerView. I need to put items in list and be able to scroll it down, if I change layouts, I get errors, please have a look at my XMLs, + I am a bit confused, where should I put my content (main_activity.xml or fragment_home.xml) because if I put anything in any of them, content will appear. Thank you.

activity_main

```
    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"

            />


    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

</FrameLayout>
```

This one stated in my "Home Fragment" java file

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

}
```

PS - At the momment there is no any content at all, only toolbar appears with 3 dot button which opens drawer (or you can slide to get there) and there is a menu to get to other fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragment_home.xml's parent as NestedScrollView so and for fragment use fragment_home.xml and for your activity use activity_main.xml

If you are new then create new project and choose NavigationDrawer it will provide readymade template.

Comment: OK I am able to change "FrameLayout" in fragment_home.xml to NestedScrollView and? "for fragment use fragment_home.xml and for your activity use activity_main.xml" - 2 years in Android Development, don't get what this means? I do this project for a while, and Drawer works fine, I don't need to make new project.

Comment: After I've changed it to NestedScrollView, my 3 dots button stoped working, I can get to drawer only by sliding(((

Comment: Toolbar become not active(